# Why can't I click on the up/down vote counter to see how the breakdown looks?

Tags: support, voting

In other Stack Exchanges, when I click on the summary vote count it resolves into how many upvotes vs downvotes.  This doesn't work in Astronomy.  Is this something that is disabled for this SE?

Answer (score 8):

Clicking on the counter to see the breakdown is an ability that you get at a higher rep level. If you check out your privileges page, you will see that you get that ability at 750 rep.

Comment: Ah.  Wonder why that is such an important ability that one has to wait for it?  I never noticed this before, because it wasn't until a couple of months ago that I discovered this functionality (on StackOverflow where my rep is almost 4000).

Comment: Anecdotally, @Cyberherbalist, this is the most-missed feature for people who start up a new site.  The primary reason its not given at lower reputations is that it requires an extra (and expensive) database query.  If you really miss seeing vote splits, you could [install this script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) to work around it.

Comment: That's cool, @JonEricson.  Some smart person came up with that, clearly.  But I'm not that keen on it - it just puzzled me and I thought there was something goofy that might need fixing.